# Problem determining if a number is an Armstrong Number

Tags: c

I'm trying to check whether or not the number provided by the user is an [armstrong number](http://everything2.net/index.pl?node_id=1407017&displaytype=printable&lastnode_id=1407017). Something is wrong though and I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Code attached below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun(int);

int main()
{
    int x,a,b,y=0;

    printf("enter the number you want to identify is aN ARMSTRONG OR NOT:");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    for(int i=1 ; i<=3 ; i++)
    {
        b = a % 10;
        x = fun(b);
        y = x+y;
        a = a/10;
    }

    if(y==a)
        printf("\narmstrong number");
    else
        printf("\nnot an armstrong number");

    return 0;
}

int fun(int x)
{
    int a;
    a=x*x*x;
    return (a);
}
```

Comment: Fastest close I saw today :))

Comment: @ash burlaczenko: it is not giving me the output correctly,as 153 is armstrong number & i want to check this out,but it fails to be an armstrong number according to the above coding,,is there anything wrong in it

Comment: @Alfred Nobel One problem might be that you're changing `a` (so it will no longer have the original value). That and all the dynamite stuff.

Comment: There are only a finite number of armstrong numbers, so you might as well create a lookup table :D

Comment: @yoda:i have got the answer.....now no need for them..:))

Comment: @Alfred, there are so very many things wrong with this code, that it would be interesting to answer them. Hope it reopens.

Comment: One obvious problem is that this code can only look for 3-digit Armstrong Numbers.

Comment: @johan: i don't think so,i hv corrected the code,by just keeping 'a' costant & varying any other variable having value same as that of 'a',in the upper for loop,& it is working now..:))

Comment: fun() ? , lol! That made me smile.

Comment: hahaha.....@stefgosselin say thanx to me,atleast i made you smile..:P

Comment: @Alfred, just because the code compiles and gives a result, does not make it good code. This is very poor code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary problem is that you don't keep a record of the number you start out with.  You divide `a` by 10 repeatedly (it ends as 0), and then compare 0 with 153.  These are not equal.

Your other problem is that you can't look for 4-digit or longer Armstrong numbers, nor for 1-digit ones other than 1.  Your function `fun()` would be better named `cube()`; in my code below, it is renamed `power()` because it is generalized to handle N-digit numbers.

---

I decided that for the range of powers under consideration, there was no need to go with a more complex algorithm for `power()` - one that divides by two etc.  There would be a saving on 6-10 digit numbers, but you couldn't measure it in this context.  If compiled with `-DDEBUG`, it includes diagnostic printing - which was used to reassure me my code was working right.  Also note that the answer echoes the input; this is a basic technique for ensuring that you are getting the right behaviour.  And I've wrapped the code up into a function to test whether a number is an Armstrong number, which is called iteratively from the main program.  This makes it easier to test.  I've added checks to the `scanf()` to head off problems, another important basic programming technique.

I've checked for most of the Armstrong numbers up to 146511208 and it seems correct.  The pair 370 and 371 are intriguing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 0
#endif

static int power(int x, int n)
{
    int r = 1;
    int c = n;
    while (c-- > 0)
        r *= x;
    if (DEBUG) printf("    %d**%d = %d\n", x, n, r);
    return r;
}

static bool isArmstrongNumber(int n)
{
    int y = 0;
    int a = n;
    int p;
    for (p = 0; a != 0; a /= 10, p++)
        ;
    if (DEBUG) printf("    n = %d, p = %d\n", n, p);
    a = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        y += power(a % 10, p);
        a /= 10;
    }
    return(y == n);
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        int a;
        printf("Enter the number you want to identify as an Armstrong number or not: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1 || a <= 0)
            break;
        else if (isArmstrongNumber(a))
            printf("%d is an Armstrong number\n", a);
        else
            printf("%d is not an Armstrong number\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Johnathan, +1, but what's up with all the `a`,`p` vars, I know that this is trivial code but what's wrong with meaningful var names?

Comment: @Johan; the original code had them, and I didn't see fit to change them.  I tend to use single letter names in trivial code.  Were it mine, I'd probably spend a little longer on the naming - but not necessarily all that much more.  (`y` ⟶ `sum`, perhaps; `p` ⟶ `ndigits`, perhaps; `a` ⟶ `number`, perhaps.  I wouldn't change `i` or `n`.  I wouldn't change the variables in `power()` - the missing one-line comment would be sufficient.  In `main()`, I might use `number` instead of `a` (because when I learned programming, `a` was implicitly a `REAL*4` - Fortran!).

Comment: @Johan: I probably would rewrite `power()` in terms of a `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` loop. I very seldom use count-down loops, and the original reason for doing so was because I counted down `n` instead of `c`, but that made the debug print inaccurate.  In retrospect, I should have done a more thorough job once the change was made to preserve `n`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem might be that you're changing `a` (so it will no longer have the original value). Also it would only match `1, 153, 370, 371, 407`. That's a hint to replace the for and test until `a` is zero and to change the function to raise to the number of digits.

Comment: Actually, it won't match 2..9 because it cubes them.  It does recognize 1 because 1 cubed is also 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int power(int, int);
int numberofdigits(int);

//Routine to test if input is an armstrong number.
//See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number if you don't know
//what that is. 

int main()
{
    int input;
    int digit;
    int sumofdigits = 0;

    printf("enter the number you want to identify as an Armstrong or not:");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    int candidate = input;
    int digitcount = numberofdigits(input);

    for(int i=1 ; i <= digitcount ; i++) 
    {
        digit = candidate % 10;
        sumofdigits = sumofdigits + power(digit, digitcount);
        candidate = candidate / 10;
    }

    if(sumofdigits == input)
        printf("\n %d is an Armstrong number", input);
    else
        printf("\n %d is NOT an Armstrong number", input);
    return 0;
}

int numberofdigits(int n);
{
  return log10(n) + 1;
}

int power(int n, int pow)
{
  int result = n;
  int i=1;
  while (i < pow) 
  {
    result = result * n; 
    i++;
  }
}
```

What was wrong with the code:

1. No use of **meaningful variable names**, making the meaning of the code hard to understand; remember code is written for humans, not compilers.
2. **Don't use confusing code** this code: `int x,a,b,y=0;` is confusing, do all vars get set to 0 or just `y`. Always put vars that get initialized on a separate line. It makes reading easier. Go the extra mile to be unambiguous, it will pay off big time in the long run.
3. **Use comments:** If you don't know what an armstrong number is, than it will be very hard to tell from your code. Put a few meaningful comments in so people know what your code it **supposed** to do. This will make it easier for you and others because they know what you meant to do **and** can see what you actually did and solve the difference if need be.
4. **use meaningful routine names** WTF does `fun(x)` do?. Never name anything `fun()` it's like fact free science, what's the point?
5. **Don't hardcode things**, your routine only accepted armstrong3 numbers, but if you can hardcode then why not do `return (input == 153) || (input == 370) || ....`

Comment: :)...i got that...........according to your code,i was varying the variable input,that's what i was doing wrong...

Comment: As @Jonathan Lefflers comment says this code only works for 3-digit numbers. According to definition of an Armstrong number on the link, you raise to the power of the (number of digits).

Comment: Apart from the algorithmic oversight about cubing versus raising to the power of the number of digits in the given number, this code can be criticized slightly. The most noticeable problem is the repeated evaluation of `numberOfDigits()` in the `for` loop. There is no checking that a valid number was entered; there is no echo of the number that is, or is not, an Armstrong number. Locality of reference suggests that `digit` should be declared inside the loop; marginally closer scrutiny suggests it is not needed at all. You've not chosen to use the `+=` and `/=` assignment operators. (Cont'd).

Comment: (Continuation) You didn't fix the idiosyncratic capitalization in the prompt message.  You don't show `#include <math.h>` but you use `log10()`.  I'll observe that you didn't refactor the test code into a function - that's less of a criticism, though it helps with the testability of the code. There are other minor layout details that could be criticized.

Comment: @Johnathan, thanks for your kind remarks, I've fixed most of them. I find the `+=` to be a bad thing, so I never use those. The digit var is in there for readability, the compiler will optimize it away so it will not affect the run time.

Comment: @Johan: just for the record, we both have one 'h' in our names.  And, because of your misspelling of my name, I didn't get the comments reported to me (first 3 characters must match).

Comment: @user, next time I'll use c++

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, the thing is that there are also Armstrong numbers that are not just 3 digits for example 1634, 8208 are 4 digit Armstrong numbers, 54748, 92727, 93084 are 5 digit Armstrong numbers and so on. so to check the number is Armstrong or not, here's what I did.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,i=0,sum=0;

    printf("Enter the number to check is an Armstrong number or not :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    
    //checking the digits of the number.
    b=a;
    while(b!=0)
    {
        b=b/10;
        i++;
    }
    // i indicates the digits

    b=a;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        int pwr = 1;
        c= a%10;

        //taking mod to get unit place and getting its nth power of their digits    

        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            pwr = pwr*c;
        }

        //Adding the nth power of the unit place

        sum += pwr;
        a = a/10;
        //Dividing the number to give the end condition
    }

    if(sum==b)
    {
        printf("The number %d is an Armstrong number",b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The number %d is not an Armstrong number",b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
Name: Rakesh Kusuma

Email Id:  rockykusuma@gmail.com

Title: Program to Display List of Armstrong Numbers in 'C' Language

*/



#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

int main()

{

int temp,rem, val,max,temp1,count;

int num;

val=0;

num=1;

printf("What is the maximum limit of Armstrong Number Required: ");

scanf("%d",&max);

printf("\nSo the list of Armstrong Numbers Before the number %d are: \n",max);

while(num <=max)

    {         
        count = 0;

        temp1 = num;

        while(temp1!=0)

        {
            temp1=temp1/10;

            count++;
        }   

        if(count<3)

        count = 3;

            temp = num;

            val = 0;

            while(temp>0)

            {

                rem = temp%10;

                val = val+pow(rem,count);

                temp = temp/10;

            }

            if(val==num)

            {

                printf("\n%d", num);

            }

     num++; 

    }

 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: this gonna work for any number.... Just give the Outer limit of the number.. And it will display all the Armstrong Numbers in between 1 and the given outer limit number.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Check No. is Armstrong or Not using *C Language***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    A:
    int n,n1,rem,ans;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter No. :: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    n1=n;
    ans=0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        rem=n%10;
        ans=ans+(rem*rem*rem);
        n=n/10;
    }

    if(n1==ans)
    {
        printf("\n Your Entered No. is Armstrong...");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Your Entered No. is not Armstrong...");
    }

    printf("\n\nPress 0 to Continue...");
    if(getch()=='0')
    {
        goto A;
    }
    printf("\n\n\tThank You...");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Note that code-only answers are liable to be deleted unless they are very well commented to explain what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a [armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) the solution you posted is missing a case where your digits are great than 3 ...armstrong numbers can be greater than 3 digits (for example 9474). Here is the code in Python, the logic is simple and it can be converted to any other language.

```
def check_armstrong(number):
    num = str(number)
    total=0
    for n in range(len(num)):
        total+=sum(int(num[n]),len(num))       

    if (number == total):
        print("we have armstrong #",total)

def sum(input,power):
    input = input**power
    return input

check_armstrong(9474)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to check whether a number is armstrong or not

```
t=int(input("nos of test cases"))
while t>0:
    num=int(input("enter any number = "))
    n=num
    sum=0
    while n>0:
        digit=n%10
        sum += digit ** 3
        n=n//10

    if num==sum:
        print("armstronng num")
    else:
        print("not armstrong")
    t-=1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the most simplest code i have made and seen ever for Armstrong number detection:

```
def is_Armstrong(y):
    if y == 0:
        print('this is 0')
    else:
        x = str(y)
        i = 0
        num = 0
        while i<len(x):
            num += int(x[i])**(len(x))
            i += 1
            if num == y:
                print('{} is an Armstrong number.'.format(num))
                break
            else:
                print('{} is not an Armstrong number.'. format(y))
is_Armstrong(1634)
```