# C program for Armstrong Number giving wrong output

Tags: c

This program is not showing 153 as Armstrong Number while for other numbers the output is correct. Like I checked for 407 it gave the right answer but when I checked 153 it showed not an Armstrong number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int no, copy, re, n = 0, ans = 0;

    printf("\n\tEnter a new number: ");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    copy = no;

    while (copy != 0) {
        copy = copy / 10;
        n++;
    }
    copy = no;

    while (copy != 0) {
        re = copy % 10;
        ans = ans + pow(re, n);
        copy = copy / 10;
    }

    if (ans == no) {
        printf("\n\t %d is an Armstrong number", no);
    } else {
        printf("\n\t %d is not an Armstrong number", no);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you step thru your code line by line in a debugger? That is the right way to debug such problems and only turn to others for help after making all efforts to debug yourself.

Comment: Your code presents any number I give as Armstrong.

Comment: 1) indent the code 2) name your variables properly.

Comment: Why are you using n = no_of_digits in the pow function. I believe this should be 3 always. Since you would want sum of the cubes of the the digits. However this should not matter for your case, since you are using a 3-digit number in the input, but this would fail for input which has more than 3 digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem determining if a number is an Armstrong Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170411/problem-determining-if-a-number-is-an-armstrong-number)

Answer (score 2):

First of all You need to give proper name for variable

Try this **code** it works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int number, originalNumber, remainder, result = 0, n = 0 ;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

     originalNumber = number;

    while (originalNumber != 0)
    {
        originalNumber /= 10;
        ++n;
    }

    originalNumber = number;

    while (originalNumber != 0)
    {
        remainder = originalNumber%10;
        result += pow(remainder, n);
        originalNumber /= 10;
    }

    if(result == number)
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.", number);
    else
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.", number);

    return 0;
}
```

In this program, the `number of digits of an integer` is calculated first and stored in `n` variable.

And the `pow()` function is used to compute the power of individual digits in each iteration of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem. It works fine. Compiling your code `gcc -o file filename.c -lm` and run as `./file` to avoid the linkage problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my Visual Studio 2013 I got below image with your code.
You may try different compiler software , I think.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct and your program performs as expected (except for the missing newlines) on my system.  If your system reports 153 as **not** being an Armstrong number, it is broken, possibly because of the floating point operation for raising the digits to the n-th power.  Try this alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int no, copy, re, i, d, n = 0, ans = 0;

    printf("Enter a new number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &no) == 1) {
        copy = no;
        while (copy != 0) {
            copy = copy / 10;
            n++;
        }
        copy = no;
        while (copy != 0) {
            d = copy % 10;
            for (re = d, i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                re *= d;
            }
            ans = ans + re;
            copy = copy / 10;
        }
        if (ans == no) {
            printf("%d is an Armstrong number\n", no);
        } else {
            printf("%d is not an Armstrong number\n", no);
        }
        getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in "pow" function cannot be used in this case. Instead you can use this:

```
               int power(int n,int r)
           {
               int i,p=1;
               for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
                p=p*n;
               return p;
           }
```

and call it in your main function

```
           result += power(remainder, n);
```

It will work for all cases.